# ios date picker to unix timestamp

Tags: ios, datepicker, timestamp

I have a date from a date picker, I need to make it a unix timestamp, I log it but get a wrong value,

here my code:

```
time_t unixTime = (time_t) [self.datePicker.date timeIntervalSince1970];

    NSLog(@"el timestamp:: %lo", unixTime);
```

this is the log

```
2012-06-01 22:13:18.543 ClientApp[50494:12503] escojio ::2012-06-01 12:12:16 +0000
2012-06-01 22:14:13.163 ClientApp[50494:12503] el timestamp:: 11762137660
```

I go to a timestamp calculator and get a completely wrong time, do i have to format it in some way?,

so what im I doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: what is this 'completely wrong time' and what is the time/format you expect to get?

Comment: you're complicating the question/answer by saying "ios date picker to unix timestamp" when you actually want "NSDate to unix timestamp". `timeIntervalSince1970` is the right choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%lo` format specifier outputs a number in octal notation. Are you sure you compared it to a Unix timestamp with the same notation?

11762137660(oct) == 1338556336(dec), which sounds about right for today.

Comment: ok I see thanks, but How would i log/ format with string, for a long ,time_t says is a long, but when I try to log it, it doesnt like %lld, %llu, or % Lf, so how to log or format correctly in (dec), my var? thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html). For a `long`, use `%ld`.